ExportTo PowerBI Api
I’m trying to export a Power BI report to PDF using the ExportTo API with the following request:
POST https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/groups/{WorkSpaceID}/reports/{ReportId}/ExportTo
{
   "format": "PDF",
   "powerBIReportConfiguration": {
      "identities": [
         {
            "username": "XXX",
            "roles": [ "XXX" ],
            "datasets": [ "XXX" ]
         }
      ]
   }
}

My effective identities configuration is correct, as I use the same setup when embedding the report on the client side, and it works fine.
However, when I try to call this API, I receive a 400 response with the following error message:
{
   "error": {
      "code": "InvalidRequest",
      "message": "Export report was called with a bad request"
   }
}

I’ve double-checked the workspace ID, report ID, and the identities configuration, but I’m still getting the error. Could anyone help me figure out what’s going wrong?
Thanks
